# Assigning a user to a new task using Microsoft Planner API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, restsharp

I'm trying to assign a user to a task using Microsoft Graph API to access Planner. **My code works fine when I'm not trying to assign someone** (by leaving out the `assignments` section), but when I add the assignments section ([following the template here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planner_post_tasks)) I get a `BadRequest` error back.

> {
>      "error": {
>       "code": "",
>       "message": "The request is invalid:\r\nValue cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: qualifiedName",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "...",
>         "date": "2018-01-30T12:23:59"
>       }
>      }
>   }

```
public TaskResponse CreateTask(string planId, string bucketId, string title, Dictionary<string, Assignment> assignments = null, DateTime? dueDateTime = null)
{
    RestRequest TaskRequest = new RestRequest("planner/tasks", Method.POST)
    {
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
    };
    Dictionary<string, object> assignees = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach(string assignment in assignments.Keys)
    {
        assignees.Add(assignment, new
        {
        });
    }
    var body = new
    {
        planId,
        bucketId,
        title,
        assignments = assignees,
        dueDateTime
    };
    TaskRequest.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), "application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse TaskResponse = GraphClient.Execute(TaskRequest);
    if (!TaskResponse.IsSuccessful)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskResponse>(TaskResponse.Content);
    return result;
}
```

I'd appreciate if anyone knows why the response is indicating I didn't supply a parameter which is never mentioned in the documentation...

Comment: It would be helpful to see what is actually going on the wire. Can you get a network trace with Fiddler and see what the JSON payload that goes across is? Because I'm able to POST as documented via Postman without getting a 400.

Comment: @JasonJohnston I used postman on the sample request and it worked. I then removed `@odata.type` from the assignee which reproduced my problem. How can I pass this parameter name (it contains special characters like `@` and `.`) in an anonymous type? It needs to go in the empty object in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using a proper class instead of an anonymous type. By doing this I was able to annotate the property with `@odata.type`, which wouldn't be acceptable as a variable name.

```
public class NewAssignment
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.type")]
    public string ODataType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("orderHint")]
    public string OrderHint { get; set; }

    public NewAssignment()
    {
        ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment";
        OrderHint = " !";
    }
}
```

This allowed me to use the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> assignees = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (string assignment in assignments.Keys)
{
    assignees.Add(assignment, new NewAssignment());
}
var body = new
{
    planId,
    bucketId,
    title,
    assignments = assignees,
    dueDateTime
};
```